# Add 2 days from an arrival calendar to a departure calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am currently using HTML 5 date type that pulls down a calendar for a person to select and arrival date.  I want to be able to add two days to the departure calendar which is the next field over in my form.  Dates are in format mm/dd/yyyy.

To be a bit more clear if someone selects lets say 07/03/2015 from the arrival calendar form field, then I want the next departure field to have 07/05/2015 already in there for them.  Hope that makes sense and

Thank you for any help on this.

Sure here is the code:  `<div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>Arrival Date *</label>
                                        <input type="date" value=""  maxlength="10" class="form-control" name="arrival" id="arrival" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <label>Departure Date *</label>
                                        <input type="date" value=""   maxlength="10" class="form-control" name="depart" id="depart" required>
                                    </div>`

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: assumes that a calendar will even show up. Not all browsers do. Would use datepicker plugin for this myself and use the API to set second date

Comment: Yup am using a jquery one for browsers that do not support the format - good tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the value of the date input field into a date object then add two days to that date object.

```
var departure = document.getElementById('departure').value;
var arrivalTime = Date.parse(departure) + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2);
var arrivalDate = new Date(arrivalTime);
// set the value on the input
document.getElementById('arrival').value = arrivalDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

You'll need to get the date into that format or HTML5 will not work. This thread will guide you in the right direction (e.g. useful libraries)

[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current date and just add two day's worth of milliseconds to it. You must handle converting from your desired format to the RFC 3339 date format (*YYYY-MM-DD*).

> #### [`input type=date – date input control`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

> "A valid full-date as defined in [[RFC 3339]](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339), with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0."

### Grammar for Date input value

You can view it [here (RFC3339 5.6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6).

```
date-fullyear   = 4DIGIT
date-month      = 2DIGIT  ; 01-12
date-mday       = 2DIGIT  ; 01-28, 01-29, 01-30, 01-31 based on
                         ; month/year

full-date       = date-fullyear "-" date-month "-" date-mday
```

### Code

```js
$(function() {
  function parseDate(dateString) {
    var parts = dateString.split('/');
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
  }
  
  function getFormattedDate(date) {
    return date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }
  
  function addTime(date, ms) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + ms);
  }

  var MS_SEC = 1000;
  var MS_MIN = MS_SEC * 60;
  var MS_HOUR = MS_MIN * 60;
  var MS_DAY = MS_HOUR * 24;
  
  var date = parseDate('07/03/2015');

  $('#arrival').val(getFormattedDate(date));
  $('#departure').val(getFormattedDate(addTime(date, MS_DAY * 2)));
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="arrival">Arrival: </label>
<input type=date id="arrival" />
<br />
<label for="departure">Departure: </label>
<input type=date id="departure" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date1 = Date.parse('07/05/2015');
date1.setDate(date1.getDate()+2);
```

now date1 will give 07/05/2015